# ACR1222L Control Event Buzzer?

Tags: nfc

I am working with the [ACR1222L](http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=product&id=ACR1222L) device from ACS. The problem is that the device beeps every time you insert/remove a card.

I need the device to not beep when a card is removed and only beep after a card has been inserted and is ready to be removed i.e. I have read/validated the card.

The API document explains the events and mentions a user controllable buzzer but not any method to change the events/buzzer on event.

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? Seems there is all kinds of controls except setting the on-card beep.

Comment: No, I couldn't resolve it. I tried setting the PICC operating parameter to disable auto polling. But then I couldn't connect to a card that was presented. I've asked ACS to provide a firmware option that doesn't have these beeps for card events. BTW, the ACR122L doesn't do this but it's unsuitable for my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just received a response from ACS regarding this issue.

There is an undocumented APDU command that allows you to specify the buzzer event.

To disable buzzer on card present/removed:

APDU

```
E00000210187
```

RESPONSE

```
E10187
```

Comment: Are there any other commands I need to send with this? I'm sending the APDU as suggested, and getting the same response, however the buzzer still sounds on insert/eject

Comment: That's very strange. I would contact ACS directly about that. I no longer have access to the email they sent me. There are requirements for a minimum firmware version which you may not satisfy.

Comment: conor it also Not worked for me as well. do you have any success in it?

Answer (score 1):

This command is [now documented](http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/2737/API-ACR1222L-1.03.pdfHAUwUTnA-7uMa3wRowd6-8eboRSQ&cad=rja) (Section 6.8, "Set Default LED and Buzzer Behaviors").

To disable buzzer on card detection:

Command: `E0 00 00 21 01 87`

Response: `E1 00 00 00 01 87`

The last byte (`87`) can also be modified for different LED/buzzer behaviours as documented.

**Important note:** This command is an escape code, not an APDU command. It may not work if you send it through the APDU interface (depending on the library you're using).